# 'StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle' findTranslations not found my default Local Translation

Tags: symfony, stofdoctrineextensions

My problem is simply... or not....

This is my config.yml for the bundle

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
default_locale: fr
translation_fallback: true
orm:
    default:
        translatable: true
```

When i use my entity translation repository with `findTranslations($entity)` The repository give me all the translation except the default local translation.

The problem is that i need to know if the default translation is in my bdd.

Is it a problem with stof or it's normal. And there's a way to solve my problem?

Thank you.

(And sorry for my english...)

Comment: I had similar problems with stof bundle. Now I use Prezent/doctrine-translatable-bundle and everything works fine. Try this bundle.